# php exec with special chars

Tags: php, encoding, exec

in my script I'm running the find command via PHPs exec function.

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "de_CH.UTF-8");
$searchString = escapeshellarg("*$searchString*");
$searchDirectory = escapeshellarg($searchDirectory);
$result = array();
exec("find $searchDirectory -type f -iname $searchString", $result);
```

There are some files with special charactes (e.g. ä, ö, ü) in their name and I want the user to be able to search for those files too. When I hard code the search like

```
exec("find $searchDirectory -type f -iname '*ä*'", $result);
```

I get the expected results back. But as soon as I use the user input it doesn't work as expected. I have already tried avoiding the passing of the parameter to escapeshellarg because I thought it might has problems with UTF-8 strings but the result was the same.

Has anyone an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you tried outputting the string being passed to exec in both cases (manual and user input)?  it might be helpful to compare the two.

Comment: user input:
find '/my/path' -type f -iname '*ä*'

hard coded:
find '/my/path' -type f -iname '*�*' 

Looks like the encodings are different. But mb_detect_encoding returns UTF-8 for both.